# If-else condition returns always false when checking an object attribute

Tags: python, oop, if-statement, setter

I'm trying to use the function 'set_disp_time' to change the disp_time value of every 'workshop' object from undefined to a certain number, depending on a formula.
The formula can take 2 forms depending from an if statement, but the condition for entering the statement returns false even when it should return true!

This is the code:
Class that calls the fuction:

```
from loader import Loader

loader_ = Loader(r'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\logistic management tool\cycles_sample.xlsx',
                 r'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\logistic management tool\demand_sample.xlsx',
                 r'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\logistic management tool\bom_sample.xlsx',
                 r'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\logistic management tool\workshops_sample.xlsx')


class Plant:

    def __init__(self, loader):

        self.loader = loader
        self.workshops = self.loader.get_workshops()

        for ws in self.workshops:
            print('workshop automation level: ', ws.automation)
            print('checks if the workshop automation is table: ', str(ws.automation) == 'table')

        # computes disposable times
        for workshop in self.workshops:
            workshop.set_disp_time()


plant = Plant(loader_)
```

```
class Workshop:

    def __init__(self, name, shifts, shift_dur, pauses, pause_dur, placing, type_, uptime):

        self.name = name
        self.shifts = shifts
        self. shift_dur = shift_dur
        self.pauses = pauses
        self.pause_dur = pause_dur
        self.placing = placing
        self.type_ = type_
        self.uptime = uptime

        self.parts = []
        self.automation = set()
        self.disp_time = 'undefined'

    def set_part(self, part):

        for phase in part.phases:
            if phase.placings > 0:
                self.automation.add('auto')
            elif phase.placings == 0 and phase.machining != phase.operator:
                self.automation.add('machine')
            elif phase.placings == 0 and phase.machining == phase.operator:
                self.automation.add('table')
            else:
                raise Exception('Undefined type for workshop, part, phase: ', self.name, part.name, phase.seq)

        if len(self.automation) != 1:
            raise Exception('more that 1 kind of automation')

        self.parts.append(part)

    # computes workshop disposable time
    def set_disp_time(self):

        print('inside set function')
        print(self.automation)
        print(self.automation == set('auto'))

        if self.automation == set('table'):
            self.disp_time = self.shifts * self.shift_dur * 60 * self.uptime - self.pauses * self.pause_dur
        elif self.automation == set('machine') or self.automation == set('auto'):
            self.disp_time = self.shifts * self.shift_dur * 60 * self.uptime
        else:
            raise Exception('Undefined disposable time for: ', self.name)
```

There's also a class that loads data from excel, but it shouldn't give any problem, since the workshop objects are created correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
from iteration_utilities import duplicates, unique_everseen
from workshop import Workshop


class Phase:

    def __init__(self, seq, workshop, machining, operator, placings, setup):

        self.seq = seq
        self.workshop = workshop
        self.machining = machining
        self.operator = operator
        self.placings = placings
        self.setup = setup


class Part:

    def __init__(self, name, phases, workshop):

        self.name = name
        self.phases = phases
        self.workshop = workshop
        self.demand = 'undefined'
        self.downstream_bom = 'undefined'

        # check if all seq are unique and in sequence
        if not all(x.seq < y.seq for x, y in zip(self.phases, self.phases[1:])):
            raise Exception('Unsorted phases in part: ', self.name)

    def set_demand(self, demand):
        self.demand = demand

    def set_downstream_bom(self, bom):
        self.downstream_bom = bom


class Loader:

    def __init__(self, cycles_file, demand_file, bom_file, workshops_file):

        self.cycles_file = cycles_file
        self.demand_file = demand_file
        self.bom_file = bom_file
        self.workshops_file = workshops_file
        self.workshops = []

        cycles = pd.read_excel(self.cycles_file, sheet_name=None)
        # checks if all part names are unique
        cycles_names = []
        for sheet in cycles:
            cycles_names.append(sheet)
        if list(duplicates(cycles_names)):
            raise Exception('Multiple parts names in cycles file: ', list(duplicates(cycles_names)))
        # list of parts sheets
        sheets = []
        for sheet in cycles:
            sheets.append(cycles[sheet])
        # fillna
        sheets = [sheets[i].fillna(0) for i in range(len(sheets))]
        # drops useless 2nd row
        sheets = [sheets[i].drop([0]) for i in range(len(sheets))]
        # drops useless columns
        sheets = [sheets[i].drop(['Unnamed: 1', 'T mac (min/pz)', 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5'], axis=1) for i in range(len(sheets))]
        # list of parts names
        parts = []
        for sheet in sheets:
            part_name = sheet.columns[0]
            workshops_set = set()
            phases_list = []
            for i in range(len(sheet.index)):
                seq = sheet.iloc[i][0]
                workshop = sheet.iloc[i][1]
                workshops_set.add(workshop)
                machining = sheet.iloc[i][2]
                operator = sheet.iloc[i][3]
                placings = sheet.iloc[i][4]
                setup = sheet.iloc[i][5]
                # checks placings coherence
                if (placings > 0 and setup > 0) or (placings > 0 and operator > 0):
                    raise Exception('Placing coherence error in part, phase: ', self.name, seq)
                phase = Phase(seq, workshop, machining, operator, placings, setup)
                phases_list.append(phase)
            for workshop in workshops_set:
                same_workshop_phases = []
                for phase in phases_list:
                    if workshop == phase.workshop:
                        same_workshop_phases.append(phase)
                part = Part(part_name, same_workshop_phases, workshop)
                parts.append(part)

        demand_data = pd.read_excel(self.demand_file)
        # checks for multiple products
        if list(duplicates(demand_data)):
            raise Exception('Multiple parts in demand file: ', list(duplicates(demand_data)))
        # demand assignment
        for part in parts:
            for col in demand_data.columns:
                if part.name == col:
                    part.set_demand(demand_data[col])

        bom_data = pd.read_excel(self.bom_file)
        bom_data = bom_data.fillna(0)
        # changes index name from numbers to parts
        new_indexes = []
        for item in bom_data['Unnamed: 0']:
            new_indexes.append(item)
        bom_data.index = new_indexes
        # deletes parts names column
        bom_data = bom_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
        # checks for multiple parts in rows and columns
        if list(duplicates(bom_data.columns)):
            raise Exception('Multiple parts in BoM columns: ', list(duplicates(bom_data.columns)))
        if list(duplicates(bom_data.index)):
            raise Exception('Multiple parts in BoM rows: ', list(duplicates(bom_data.index)))
        # checks if there are reciprocal dependencies
        coordinates = []
        for column in bom_data.columns:
            for row in bom_data.index:
                if row != column and bom_data.at[row, column] > 0:
                    coordinates.append({row, column})
        duplicates_list = list(duplicates(coordinates))
        if duplicates_list:
            raise Exception('Reciprocal dependencies in the BoM: ', duplicates_list)
        # sets downstream BoM
        for part in parts:
            part.set_downstream_bom(bom_data.loc[part.name])
        # checks coherence of parts data
        if len(list(unique_everseen(list(bom_data.columns) + list(bom_data.index)))) != len(sheets):
            raise Exception('Incoherent data about parts names in the BoM')

        workshops_data = pd.read_excel(self.workshops_file, sheet_name=None)
        # checks if there are turns and turn durations
        for workshop in workshops_data:
            if int(workshops_data[workshop]['Shifts']) == 0:
                raise Exception('Missing shifts in workshop: ', workshop)
            if float(workshops_data[workshop]['Shift duration (h)']) == 0:
                raise Exception('Missing Shift duration in workshop: ', workshop)
        # checks for multiple names
        if list(duplicates(workshops_data)):
            raise Exception('Duplicate names in workshops data: ', list(duplicates(workshops_data)))
        # checks if all the workshops in the parts are present in the workshop file
        for part in parts:
            for phase in part.phases:
                if phase.workshop not in workshops_data:
                    raise Exception('workshop in cycles not found in workshops file: ', phase.workshop)
        # creates workshop obj
        for workshop in workshops_data:
            name = workshop
            shifts = int(workshops_data[workshop]['Shifts'])
            shift_dur = float(workshops_data[workshop]['Shift duration (h)'])
            pauses = int(workshops_data[workshop]['Pauses/shift'])
            pause_dur = float(workshops_data[workshop]['Pause duration (min)'])
            placing = float(workshops_data[workshop]['Placing duration (min)'])
            type_ = str(workshops_data[workshop]['Type'])
            uptime = float(workshops_data[workshop]['uptime'])
            workshop = Workshop(name, shifts, shift_dur, pauses, pause_dur, placing, type_, uptime)
            self.workshops.append(workshop)

        # setting parts for workshops
        for part in parts:
            for workshop in self.workshops:
                if workshop.name == part.workshop:
                    workshop.set_part(part)

    def get_workshops(self):
        return self.workshops
```

This is the result I get:

workshop automation level:  {'auto'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'machine'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'machine'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'table'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'table'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'table'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'table'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

workshop automation level:  {'table'}

checks if the workshop automation is table:  False

inside set function
{'auto'}
False

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\plant.py", line 25, in 
plant = Plant(loader_)

File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\plant.py", line 22, in **init**
workshop.set_disp_time()

File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\workshop.py", line 48, in set_disp_time
raise Exception('Undefined disposable time for: ', self.name)

Exception: ('Undefined disposable time for: ', 'clav acciaio')

Comment: which if returns false?

Comment: That’s a whole awful lot of code. Can you pare it down to just the part that’s giving you an unexpected result?

Comment: If you look at the results, all the if statements return false, even if the workshop automation level is correctly set to 'table'. It should return false only if it is 'auto' or 'machine'.

Comment: Just don't look at the last class, the workshop objects are created correctly, I already checked this. The problem must be between plant and workshop classes, probably inside the set_disp_time function.

Comment: `set('auto')` is the same thing as `set(['a', 'u', 't', 'o'])` - `self.automation` is certainly never going to be equal to that.  You want to write tests like `'auto' in self.automation`, I think.

Comment: first you could use `print()`, print(type())` to see what you have in variables in which part of code is executed - ie. `print(self.automation, set("auto"))` and `print(type(self.automation), type(set("auto")))`. It is called `"print debuging"`